# Problem adding object to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

I am having problems adding objects to my NSMutableArray.  It seems that something gets added (object count increases by 1 in debugger), but the only thing added is a 0x0 (null) instead of the address of an object.  I've read through everything somewhat relevant that I could find, but I couldn't find anything that seemed to answer this issue.  Most related posts seem to revolve around memory management, but the solution is not jumping out at me.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

I've included what I think are the relevant parts of the code.  Please tell me if you need to see anything more.

### GamePlayView.h

```
@interface GamePlayView : UIViewController 
{
    Player *gamePlayer;
    NSMutableArray *boardObjects;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) Player *gamePlayer;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *boardObjects;

@end
```

### GamePlayView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // Create player

    Player *tempPlayer = [[Player alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    if (tempPlayer == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"GamePlayView viewDidLoad: null Player");
    }
    else gamePlayer = tempPlayer;

    // Create array of board objects

    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.boardObjects = newArray;
    [self.boardObjects addObject: gamePlayer];  // First breakpoint here
    topObject = 0;

    BoardObject *mine = [[BoardObject alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];

    [self.boardObjects addObject: mine];  // Second breakpoint here
    topObject = 1;

    [super viewDidLoad];

} // End viewDidLoad
```

I put breakpoints at the addObject lines (commented in code).  When execution stops at the first breakpoint, the debugger shows a good tempPlayer, and a good gamePlayer (both with the same address).  It shows 0 objects in boardObjects, like this:

```
boardObjects = (_NSArrayM *) 0x4b22080 0 objects
```

When I step over this breakpoint, the debugger shows 1 object in boardObjects, as follows:

```
boardObjects = (_NSArrayM *) 0x4b22080 1 objects
    0 = (NSObject *) 0x0
```

When I continue program execution, and the debugger stops at the next breakpoint, I also see a good mine object, with boardObjects still described as above.  After stepping over this breakpoint, boardObjects now looks like this:

```
boardObjects = (_NSArrayM *) 0x4b22080 2 objects
    0 = (NSObject *) 0x0
    1 = (NSObject *) 0x0
```

Comment: NSArray's cannot hold `nil`. I don't have an explanation for what you're seeing in the debugger.

Comment: You don't seem to be showing enough. You have a variable gamePlayer, but it is not a local variable and it doesn't seem to be declared in the @interface either. So what is it? And why are you adding it a second time, instead of the mine object? And why is the mine only allocated but not initialized?

Comment: Can't explain this based on what I see here, but a couple of questions: (1) How is gamePlayer declared (2) Are you using garbage collection or ARC (3)why is the BoardObject allocated but not init'd (4) are you intentionally adding gamePlayer to the array twice

Comment: Thanks Rudy and Tim.  Good questions and observations.  gamePlayer is a property of GamePlayView.  The second addObject should be for mine, not gamePlayer.  The mine should be initialized.  I've adjusted the code above to reflect these three issues.  I don't know if I'm using garbage collection or ARC.  I haven't specifically selected anything.  How do I check?

Comment: In the debugger display gamePlayer and mine before you put them into the array.  When you discover that the values are nil, look at your implementations of init in Player and BoardObject, and realize that the init methods are not returning "this".

Comment: Daniel, both gamePlayer and mine are good, non-nil, as the debugger stops at the addObject break points (and after the addObject has been performed).

Comment: Did you try purely: `NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init]; [self.boardObjects addObject:obj];` and also remove that `topObject` variable?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the case that tempPlayer is a local variable, after returning from the function, the local variable is automatically released.

Comment: I can't imagine that happen, unless tempPlayer is autoreleased. I don't see that happen in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested I display the boardObjects in the code anyway, even though it looked from the debugger that I only had null objects.  I inserted this code after the last addObject:

```
NSLog(@"self.boardObjects is: %@", [self.boardObjects description]);
```

This displayed good objects:  the gamePlayer and the mine!

I did verify that immediately before this NSLog statement, and immediately after, the debugger still displays two null entries in boardObjects.

It seems like the answer to my original question, then, is that the code itself is correct.  However, it seems now that I have a new question:  Does this mean I'll never be able to view into an NSMutableArray from within the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign @property with `self.`

```
self.gamePlayer = tempPlayer;
```